# Null pointer exception while using simple example of jdbcTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am learning JdbcTemplate with Spring and when i am running my java application i am getting null pointer on this line:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql, id);
```

Please find the whole class below:

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDAO{

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
      public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        dataSource = ds;
      }

    public Map getCustomerById(String id) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?";

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql, id);
    }
```

Please find my SpringContext file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
        configure as beans -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.tuto.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please find my Main method below:

```
public class JdbcTemplateApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // if you have time,
        // it's better to create an unit test rather than testing like this :)

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "integration.xml");

        CustomerDAO customerDAO = (CustomerDAO) context.getBean("customerDAO");

        Map customerA = customerDAO.getCustomerById("1");
        System.out.println("Customer A : " + customerA);

    }
}
```

Please find below my exception in eclipse console:

```
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tuto.dao.impl.CustomerDaoImpl.getCustomerById(CustomerDaoImpl.java:23)
    at com.tuto.main.JdbcTemplateApp.main(JdbcTemplateApp.java:23)
```

Any idea why it is null please?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change setDataSource to:

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `jdbcTemlpate` instance variable. In this case it's initialized as null and you're getting `NullPointerException` (you can't call methods on `null`). You need to initialize `jdbcTemplate` by yourself.

To quote [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is
>   initialized with a default value when it is created [...] For all
>   reference types the default value is null.

Comment: I took me 3 hours After reading your answer. I got output. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport` in your DAOImpl Class and use inherited `getJdbcTemplate()` method to get the jdbcTemplate. in this case you can remove the variable jdbcTemplate from your class